# Amount of watts on a phone charger

Tags: charger, 5v

I'm building a phone charger, and I'm curious about the output power. We know that a phone battery charge on 5 V, and let's say the overall resistance of the charging circuit in the phone is about 200 Ω (not sure, I googled it) how would a 2 A for example pass?

For a clear picture, I'll tell you what I'm thinking. If we have a 5 V supply on a 200 Ω resistor the current that pass the resistor is 5/200 = 25 mA. How would it be a 2 A in the example above?!

In other words what does the 2 A mean? And would we use like an amplifier for this kind of problems?

Comment: Is it via USB? If yes, you need to provide USB handshake to deliver more than 1 A IIRC. Sine the charger input of a phone is a DC/DC converter, impedance or resistance is meaningless. How did you measure 200 ohm?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the 200 Ω equivelant circuit is incorrect. If you wanted to test the power supply at 2 A then you would need R = V / I = 5 / 2 = 2.5 Ω as a test load.

> In other words what does the 2 A mean?

It just means that a 5 V, 2 A rated PSU can supply up to 10 W, if required by the load.

> And would we use like an amplifier for this kind of problems?

Not really. The power supply has a control circuit to maintain output voltage up to its rated current. An amplifier, on the other hand, takes an input signal and amplifies its voltage or current using power than is supplied from a power supply.